# How to remove "ok" response from Slack slash-command?

Tags: php, laravel, post, slack

I created my own Timer app in Slack. And I already integrated Incoming Webhook for this. My sample slash-command is "/in". So when the HTTP post is ok, it returns to the user a message with "Your name has timed in" but it will also return a response but visible to you.

[image: See Screenshot]

```
public function slack(Request $request)
    {
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        $payload = '{"text" : "'. $request->user_name .' has time in"}';
        $hook = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/some-string-here';
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $hook);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = 'You are now timed in.';

        return $response;

    }
```

Now my problem is how to remove that word "ok".

I am using Laravel/PHP for this.

Comment: Gonna need more code than that to help you. Where is your method returning to? Did you start from an existing project out there which you based this on? Got a link to it?

Comment: @Ultimater this is a new installed laravel app. That's all i have in my Controller, and my route for that is Route::post('slack', 'TimerController@slack').

Comment: please add the code that is actually sending $response to the calling service. e.g. `echo $response;`

Comment: `return $response` is already the code for sending the request. in Laravel, all returns are formatted to JSON.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to remove the "ok" that is added to the response?

Comment: At least for me, I was able to fix this by changing "curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);" to "curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);" - it seems that with it set to 0, it was echoing out the "ok", whereas if it were set to 1, it would be return it in function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using express.js, but I found that

`return res.sendStatus(200);` made Slack post an ephemeral OK message, but using

`return res.status(200).send('')` would suppress the OK message.

So while you want to send back a 200 status, you want to make sure the payload is empty.